How were East German citizens who defected to West Berlin able to travel to the rest of West Germany? (If at all)
The common image we have of people defecting from the GDR is that they went to  West Berlin.
To my understanding West Germans could travel out of West Berlin through East Germany, via plane, train, or car, passing through checkpoints.
I also know that the East German state was hostile to those who defected and saw them as criminals. This poses the question of how would the GDR citizens who defected to West Berlin, be able to get out of West Berlin - either to other parts of Germany or other countries.
Generally, we hear of people escaping "to the West" and it would be odd, if it meant West Berlin only when it sounds like was West Germany.
I cannot find much information about it - I found a tread here pointing out that it would be hard for a former East German citizen to travel to any country in the Soviet Block and a thread on Quora mentioning how travel out of West Berlin looked like, but nothing how it looked specifically for defectors from GDR.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Leaving the East German Democratic Republik without a permit or not returning after an allowed stay was a crime, punishable by a prison sentence of up to two years. If a defector later entered the area of East Germany, he/she could be arrested.
Citizens of West Berlin and of West Germany were free to travel by air to and from West-Berlin, neither the East German government nor the Soviets had a right to control passengers in the airports of the three Western Allies. Since defectors immediately got full citizenship and a West German or Berlin passport, that is also true for them.
The airlines flying between West Berlin and West Germany weren't German, but operated by American, French and British companies with licences issued by the Allied Control Council. This avoided the dicey question of West German planes entering the East German airspace. Pan Am, British Airways and Air France were operating the big line services.
Legally, the transit traffic between West Berlin and West Germany became an exception after the ratification of the Transit Agreement in 1972. From then on, the East German Government assured not to arrest anyone using the fixed and controled transit routes, even if there was an arrest warrant for them. The only reason to intervene was a "misuse" of the transit, for example by making contact to East Germans, leaving the route or loitering longer than necessary to pass through the country.
In practice, a lot of people still preferred to either not travel at all, or to use air travel, for fear of coming into contact with East German authorities. A lot of rumors were floating about, and it was obvious that regarding its border, East Germany did a lot of things that were highly invasive. If a border guard might take your car completely apart down to the last screw in case of entering the GDR, would he really refrain from doing so if you had a transit visum? If you could be held in isolated custody for hours "to clear up an issue" in case of entering, would he really only look at you through your car window if you had a transit visum? These guys were perceived as the impersonation of a completely ruthless state power.
Additionally, air travel was cheap and competitively fast, if you were near a West German Airport. Flying time between Frankfurt and Berlin was 50 minutes, with maybe half an hour on- and offboarding at each end. Compare that to trains that were stopped for hours at a time on the borders (I once had to take an overnight train that ran nine hours), or cars where a ride from border to border, including passing the controls, would have taken between two hours (to Helmstedt) and five hours (Herleshausen before the Autobahn border crossing was built in 1984).

I grew up in a USA at a time there being an East and West Germany and an East and West Berlin was a fact of life. It was very often talked about and reported on as a "divided city." However, it was rarely if ever mentioned that West Berlin was entirely surrounded by East Germany. Suspiciously so, looking back on it.

@T.E.D. That calls for an old joke: We know that at the North pole every direction you look is South, and at the South pole, every direction is North. That surely means that West Berlin is the West pole, because every direction you look is East. (Depends a bit on the fact that in German everyday parlance, "Ostdeutschland" was simply called "der Osten" – the East.)

The WIkipedia article on Tempelhof Airport has a lot of information on aviation in West Berlin as well as links to related articles.

@StuartF Remember to also look at the article about Tegel Airport, which replaced Tempelhof as the hub for all commercial jet operations from 1960 (Air France) resp. 1975 (PanAm and BEA) onwards.

It was easy but risky. East Germans would simply drive to the road that connected Berlin to the west, get on it, and drive to the West German border. Some cash may need to change hands at this point. I know a number of people who did it.

Adding more detail and sources would improve this answer.

uh, no. That entire road was fenced in with no access from the GDR apart from a few military and police checkpoints. I've driven that road a few times. And yes, there were east German checkpoints on that road, I'm sure any GDR citizen driving there would be arrested if they didn't have the proper permits.

That would be anecdotal evidence - if you had provided any.
